# Raspberry Pi alternative with Audio Input

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi

I am looking for RPi alternatives with audio inputs. I prefer 192kHz 24 bit line in yet any audio input also fine.

There was a board like pi which have input jack at just below of output jack but I didn't find it. Maybe you know it.

Please let me know your alternatives.